# Adding database entries together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making a site which allows admins to basically add points for a user.

At this point in time, I have a table, where `id_child` is unique, and `id_points` changes. So a constant stream of `id_points` can come in, however, it will only show the latest `id_points`, not the total.

I am wondering how I could go about creating a PHP script that could add all of those together.

[image]

From the image, the idea is that I want all id_points values added together to give a total, and this is for the same id_child

Comment: SQL has a built-in `SUM` function. You can use that to find the sum of rows. Show some actual code of what you've tried and your SQL  table structure for better help

Comment: Could you show us the table(s)?

Comment: You can get the database to do the maths for you. You need to use the sum function within your query. More info here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: The thing is, the SUM function only works for a row. I want it to work for specific rows (the ones with the same number id_child)

Comment: @Anthony Then use `sum()` with `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL [`sum()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/sum.php) funciton:

```
select sum(id_points) from table `table_name` where `id_child` = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope i understood right.

First if you want to show only the latest points added you have to create another table `#__points` where you will keep every new change of points.

You need 3 columns `id` as `PRIMARY` and `AUTO_INCRENMENT` , `pts` and `user_id` . `user_id` will be FK to `id_child`.

So when you want to add a new record :

```
INSERT INTO `#__points` (pts,user_id) VALUES ("$pts",$id)
```

When you want to select last inserted value for each admin :

```
SELECT * from `#__points` where user_id=$id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```